# MVC C# Session Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I already posted this question but no one answered my comments/errors I had. How do I get the text entered in @Html.TextBox("SearchString") in my index viw to welcome view using session variables?

HomeController.Cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Newproject.Models;

namespace Newproject.Controllers
{
 public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Gender(WelcomeVm model)

    {
        model.Genders = new List<SelectListItem>
   {
     new SelectListItem { Value="Male", Text="Male"},
     new SelectListItem { Value="Female", Text="Female"}
    };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Welcome(WelcomeVm model)
     {
       return View(model);
     }
    public object Final { get; set; }
 }
 }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
}

<br />
@Html.Label("Name")
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Gender", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextBox("Name");
<input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" placeholder="test" type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Gender.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class WelcomeVm
{
public string Name { set; get; }
public string Gender { set; get; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Genders { set; get; }
}
```

Gender.cshtml

```
@model WelcomeVm
@using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<p>Hello @Model.Name what is your gender</p>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.Genders)
@Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Name)
<input type="submit" />
}
```

Welcome.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
}

@model WelcomeVm
<p>Hello @Model.Name who is a @Model.Gender</p>
```

Comment: If you don't get answers, then asking the same question again is not the right way. Instead improve/edit your existing question, add more information to help people answer it.

Comment: Please update the title to your questions with... an actual question.  Just saying technology key words will most likely get you less visits.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Session or ViewBag to pass data around. You can simply use the view model you have.

So in your index view,

```
@Html.Label("Name")  
@using (Html.BeginForm("Gender", "Home"))
{
  @Html.TextBox("Name");
  <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit"    value="Submit" />
}
```

and in your `Gender` action method use the same view model as your parameter type. When the form is posted, the default model binder will map the posted form values ot an object of the `WelcomeVm` class.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Gender(WelcomeVm model)
{
   model.Genders = new List<SelectListItem>
   {
         new SelectListItem { Value="Male", Text="Male"},
         new SelectListItem { Value="Female", Text="Female"}
   };
   return View(model);
}
```

and in the `Gender.cshtml` view which is again strongly typed to the same view model.

```
@model WelcomeVm
@using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <p>Hello @Model.Name what is your gender</p>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.Genders)
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.Name)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

and in the Welcome action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Welcome(WelcomeVm model)
{
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the Welcome.cshtml view,which is again strongly typed to your view model,

```
@model WelcomeVm
<p>Hello @SearchString who is a @Model.Gender</p>
```

Comment: In my Gender.cshtml page it gives me an error. @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.Genders) says its an InvalidOperationException was unhandeled by used Code

Comment: I did everything as you said Shyju but the name entered in the index page text page doesn't show up in the welcome page

Comment: For your first problem, Are you loading the Genders collection in the Gener action method ? For the second comment, Are you seeing the name in second view(Gender) ?

Comment: Ya I'm seeing the name in in gender view

Comment: my first problem error is fixed doesn't show up anymore

Comment: You need to keep the name in Gender view using a hidden field so that it available when you submit the form. See my updated answer. `@Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.Name)`

Comment: Check the view source of your Gender view and see whether you have the name in there

Comment: Why do you have a parameter in your action method called `SearchString` ? That is not needed. the Name property takes care of the entered name,

Comment: Thank You very Much  I was missing "Model.Name" in  @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Name, Model.Name)

Comment: Really Appreciate all your help